# Search for #N/A! in a sheet, msgbox if found, other sub when not found

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, error-handling

Struggle with a sub to search through sheet for #N/A! or #REF! errors.
It has to popup a msgbox when at least one error found. If no errors, should execute other sub - sprzedaz2.

As long as there is at least one error, it works okay. But for a sheet without errors, it breaks and I can't think of a solution.

What I have so far:

```
Sub X_SPR_sprawdzbledy()
Application.Goto Workbooks("generator_komunikatow.xlsm").Sheets("komunikat_OS_sprzedaz").Range("a1")
On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
If Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Cells.Count = 0 Then
Call sprzedaz2
Else:
MsgBox ("UWAGA! Znaleziono " & Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Cells.Count & " bledow!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "SPRAWDZ KOMORKI Z #N/A! lub #REF!")

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue: If `SpecialCells` doesn't find anything (in your case, no cells with errors), it will throw a runtime error, you need to catch this error (a Range never can have 0 cells). The following code assigns the result of `SpecialCells` to a variable. If it fails because nothing was found, the variable remains unassigned which means it still holds `Nothing`.

```
Dim errorCells As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set errorCells = Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Cells
On Error GoTo 0
If errorCells Is Nothing Then    ' No errors in cells
    Call sprzedaz2
Else
    MsgBox "UWAGA! Znaleziono " & errorCells.Count & " bledow!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "SPRAWDZ KOMORKI Z #N/A! lub #REF!"
End If
```

N.B. get rid of the `:` after the `Else`...